# How to edit images using javascript in real time and save the edited image on the server?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, web-applications

Is it possible to edit images using a javascript library and then send the edited image to the server for saving.
Edits will be in real time, means the user can see the edit result in the same time he is editing without the need to refresh the page.

I want a javascript library to do some edits on an image on a webpage 'such as crop, resize, rotate,...' and send send the edited result to the server.

How this can be done or if there any smart work around to something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries mentioned don't seem to be fully cross browser.  As far as I know there is no fully cross browser compliant way to edit pixel data on the client.

The current best approach would be to do these manipulations on the server.  You can still do this real time using a web service.

As an example see the image editor in TinyMCE which supports crop, rotate, resize, flip, all from the client without a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

[Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/) is an image manipulation library;  once you've modified the image, some sort of post back / upload call from the script will be able to upload the image provided you've implemented the needed functionality to do so.

Answer (score 0):

An incomplete list to be sure, but these are two that come to mind which allow you do a wide variety of editing on the client side and push back to the server.

- [PIxastic](http://www.pixastic.com/)
- [AIE](http://www.ajax-image-editor.com/)

And there are numerous less complete image editing tools for simply cropping or adjusting contrast as well.

Answer (score -1):

[jcrop](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/crop) is what you are looking for .

Comment: but this is just for croping, i will need some other edits, such as resize and rotate.

Comment: Dead link. No explanation on why or how jcrop should be used.